# dropdownlist , show 2nd dropdownlist based on the first dropdownlist php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I would like to do a drop down in my php.

This mean that , I will be having 2 drop down list.
First dropdown list : snacks&tibits, beverage, toiletries
second dropdown list : different subcategory based on the category in first dropdown list.

What outcome I would like to get is
When I select the First dropdown list, and choose snacks&tibits, in the second dropdown list, it will only show the subcategory that is related to snacks& tibits and nothing else, so on and so forth for the other 2.

I did a try out , however when I try to retrieve the second dropdown list, it is always blank.
Can someone tell me how can I improve my code?

Thank you

```
 <td width="175">Category:</td>
 <td width="405">

 <label>
 <select name="category_sel" id="category_sel" required="required" >
   <?php
do {  
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row_sup_cat['category']?>"><?php echo $row_sup_cat['category']?></option>
   <?php
} while ($row_sup_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sup_cat));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($sup_cat);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($sup_cat, 0);
      $row_sup_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sup_cat);
  }
?>
 </select>
 </label>



  </tr>
 <tr>

 <td>Subcategory:</td>
 <td>
<select name="subcatgory" id="subcatgory" required="required" >
  <?php
do {  
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_sup_subcat['subcategory']?>"><?php echo $row_sup_subcat['subcategory']?></option>
  <?php
} while ($row_sup_subcat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sup_subcat));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($sup_subcat);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($sup_subcat, 0);
      $row_sup_subcat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sup_subcat);
  }
?>
</select>

 </td>
  </tr>
```

....

```
  <?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
$query_sup_cat = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM supermarket";
$sup_cat = mysql_query($query_sup_cat, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sup_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sup_cat);
$totalRows_sup_cat = mysql_num_rows($sup_cat);
$query_sup_cat = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM supermarket";
$sup_cat = mysql_query($query_sup_cat, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sup_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sup_cat);
$totalRows_sup_cat = mysql_num_rows($sup_cat);

$colname_sup_subcat = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['category_sel'])) {
  $colname_sup_subcat = $_POST['category_sel'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
$query_sup_subcat = sprintf("SELECT subcategory FROM supermarket WHERE subcategory = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_sup_subcat, "text"));
$sup_subcat = mysql_query($query_sup_subcat, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sup_subcat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sup_subcat);
$totalRows_sup_subcat = mysql_num_rows($sup_subcat);



?>
```

Comment: where is the code to fill the second drop-down based on the first drop-down value?

Comment: You won't be able to do this dynamically with PHP unless you post the data first, then act upon that data with PHP a second time, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: @dawson what do you mean?

Comment: Still not enough. How are you updating second dropdown? Through ajax? If so, then add ajax code as well.

Comment: PHP renders the page, and gives you the contents of the 1st dropdown. But then PHP is done. It won't know the first dropdown has been updated unless you process that change via form post, or get. If you don't want to process that dropdown in that way, you'll want to look into a javascript or ajax solution to populate the second dropdown based on the onChange event.

Comment: @kumar_v via database, using form variable

Comment: However you need to use ajax or page submit to do filter the second dropdown. Do you have code for ajax? or do you need code?